# Is there a better (faster, more convenient) way to concatenate multiple (nullable) objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I've ended up writing my own helper-class to concatenate objects: [ConcatHelper.cs](https://gist.github.com/neuhausf/94b68fab357d51df19e1).

You see some examples in the gist, but also in the following snippet:

```
model.Summary = new ConcatHelper(", ")
.Concat(diploma.CodeProfession /* can be any object, will be null checked and ToString() called */)
.BraceStart() // if everything between the braces is null or empty, the braces will not appear
.Concat(diploma.CodeDiplomaType)
.Concat(label: DiplomaMessage.SrkRegisterId, labelSeparator: " ", valueDecorator: string.Empty, valueToAdd: diploma.SrkRegisterId)
.BraceEnd()
.Concat(diploma.CodeCountry)
.BraceStart()
.Concat(diploma.DateOfIssue?.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) // no separator will be added if concatenated string is null or empty (no ", ,")
.BraceEnd()
.Concat(DiplomaMessage.Recognition, " ", string.Empty, diploma.DateOfRecognition?.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
.ToString(); // results in something like: Drogist / Drogistin (Eidgenössischer Abschluss, SRK-Registrierungsnummer 3099-239), Irland (1991)
```

**Benefits:**

- Does the null checks for you, avoids if/else branches.
- Supports labeling, decorating and delimiting values. Doesn't add a label if the value will be null.
- Joins everything, fluent notation - less codes
- Good to do summaries of domain-objects.

**Contra:**

- Rather slow:

  - <s>I measured 7ms for the above example</s>
  - I measured 0.01026ms per concatenation in a real-life example (see [unit-test gist](https://gist.github.com/neuhausf/dbeb3f9435c869af999d))
  - It's not static (could it be?)
  - Needs a list to keep track of everything.
  - Probably an overkill.

So as I am now starting to override a lot of `ToString()` methods of domain objects, I am unsure, if there is a better way.

By *better* I basically mean:

- Is there a library that already does the stuff I need?
- If not, can it be speed up without losing the convenient fluent-notation?

So I would be happy if you show me either a convenient way to achieve the same result without my helper, or helping me improving this class.

Greetings,
flo

**Update:**

Look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/neuhausf/dbeb3f9435c869af999d) for a real-life UnitTest.

Comment: 7ms is far too slow, just needs to be optimized. For example, why use Expression when you just Compile() and execute it immediately. This could well be the slowest part.

Comment: `(typeof(T).IsValueType || valueToAdd != null)` what about nullable value types that are null? That bit should perhaps just be `valueToAdd != null`.

Comment: @usr thx, I updated the gist!

Comment: Either your ToString()-methods are to slow or your measurement is flawed. When I take your example and replace those objects with strings, I get 3.3us per call.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I was kind of lazy and looked at the new feature in the visual studio debugger (time for a step). Now I wrote some code to test it better (see my updated question for the gist).

Comment: If this is good enough for you, what's the problem? You could make this a lot cleaner (for example, using immutable data structures with fluent syntax is usually a good idea), but caring about whether something is or isn't overkill is... an overkill. Measure, profile - if it's good enough for your use case, it doesn't really matter if it takes 1ms or a minute.

Comment: @Luaan you are probably right - probably I care too much ;) I was just wondering that there seems no existing library for this. Is my usecase really that special? I mean combining strings is something you do really often for summaries, reports, visualizing data in grids... I didn't want to reinvent the wheel, but I guess the performance impact isn't that big even if I display a lot of domain-objects in a grid.

Comment: The thing is, something like this is absurdly trivial to implement, and yet if you wanted to make one generic implementation that allows you to do all the possible uses... you can', really. It's a simple problem that doesn't have a simple abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any real problem with your code. But I would prefer a more streamlined syntax. It may look like this in the end:

```
string result = ConcatHelper.Concat(
                    diploma.CodeProfession,
                    new Brace(
                        diploma.CodeDiplomaType,
                        new LabeledItem(label: DiplomaMessage.SrkRegisterId, labelSeparator: " ",
                            valueDecorator: string.Empty, valueToAdd: diploma.SrkRegisterId) 
                        ),
                    diploma.CodeCountry,
                    new Brace(
                        diploma.DateOfIssue?.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        ),
                    DiplomaMessage.Recognition
                    ).ToString();
```

- no wall of Text
- you do not have to repeat Concat over and over again
- now chance to mix up the braces

`Concat()` would be of the type `static ConcatHelper Concat(objs object[] params)` in this case. `Brace` and `LabeledItem` need to be handled by ConcatHelper of course (`if (obj is LabeledItem) { ... }`).

Regarding your contras:

- It should be fast enough (10us/ call should be okay). If you really need it faster, you probably should use a single `String.Format()`
- `Concat` can be static. Just create the ConcatHelper-object inside the Concat-call.
- Yes, it needs a list. Is there a problem?
- It may be overkill, it may not. If you use this type of code regularly, Utility classes can save you much time and make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Variant 1 - stream like

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
const string delimiter = ", ";
var first = true;
Action<object> append = _ => {
    if(null!=_){
        if(!first){ sb.Append(delimiter);}
        first = false;
        sb.Append(_.ToString()); 
    }
}
append(diploma.X);
append(diploma.Y);
...
```

Another one - with collection

```
var data = new List<object>();
data.Add(diploma.X);
data.Add(diploma.Y);
...
var result = string.Join(", ",data.Where(_=>null!=_).Select(_=>_.ToString()));
```

It's not much efficient but it allow you addition step between data preparation and joining to do somwthing over collection itself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I use variant 2 for some simple concatenations. Can you make an example how the unit-test in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/neuhausf/dbeb3f9435c869af999d) would look like?

Comment: Just create expected string manually and check it against auto concatenation with Assert.AreEqual, for multiple checking use TestCase with expected result and some data to construct Diploma